# Bash: Capturing the output from a command and conditionally processing it

Tags: bash

*Is* there a better way to handle the following standard-ish way of conditionally handling output?

```
output="$(program | grep -E 'some text')"
if [ ! -z "$output" ]; then
    echo "$output" | mail -s 'captured output' to
fi
```

I was thinking of something along the lines of the obviously wrong

```
program | grep -E 'some text' | { [[ $? == 0 ]] && mail -s 'captured output' to; }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a way to do it without having to capture the output.  In some cases (i.e. huge output), this could be preferable.  Something like this, which can be reused easily :

```
execute_on_input()
{
  local c=
  local r=0
  IFS= read -r -n 1 c  || r=$?
  [[ "$c" ]] || return 0
  { echo -n "$c" ; [[ $r != 0 ]] || cat ; } | "$@"
}


program | grep -E 'some text' | execute_on_input mail -s 'captured output'
```

The function checks if it can read something, and if it cannot it exits without launching the command passed in the position arguments ("$@").  If output is found, it is piped to the command received in positional arguments (the first character read first, then, with `cat`, the rest of the output that was not read with the first `read`).

Comment: That will work fine with grep, but it relies on the input not being a single unterminated line. (Read fails if the line it read was unterminated even if it successfully read some data)

Comment: @rici  You are right, missed that.  I updated my answer with code that should output unterminated streams.  I changed it to peek only at the first character in the stream too, which would avoid reading too much in case there are no newlines in the stream.

Comment: @Larry Oops...  I made changes to a previous version, and forgot to replace this one.  Thanks for catching it.  I put `r` everywhere in my code (but you may chose whatever variable name you prefer, of course).

Answer (score 1):

The exit status of `grep` will tell you if there was a match or not.

```
if output=$(program | grep -E 'some text'); then
    printf '%s' "$output" | mail -s 'captured output' to
fi
```

However, `mail` (at least the version I am looking at) has an option `-E` that prevents an empty message from being sent, making the check unnecessary.

```
program | grep -E 'some text' | mail -E -s 'captured output' to
```

Comment: Good point - I didn't know about mail -E, but I'm not marking it as the accepted answer. Let's say the mail command is some other command that doesn't do anything special with no input.

Answer (score 0):

You can replace `if [ ! -z "$output" ]` with `if [ -n "$output" ]` (or `if [ -n "${output}" ]`).  Other possibilities will do the same, so why make it more difficult to read?
The explicit use of `test` will show what you are doing:

```
test -n "${output}" && echo "output filled"
```